# deactivate button on gallery slider

Tags: javascript

I'm am trying to make my javascript/jquery slider button deactivated when it reaches the the end of the scrolling images( when the images have moved all the way to the right, the MoveRight button must be deactivated and only leave MoveLeft button active, same for the move LeftButton), can anybody help with this ? Im not sure if im using 
.attr() and removeAttr() correctly. I have pasted my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//Check width of Gallery div
var galleryWidth = $("#Gallery").innerWidth();
//Check width of GalleryItem
var NoListed = $("ul.GalleryItem li").length;
var galleryItemWidth = 1881;    

$('.MoveRight')
$('.GalleryItem').css('width', galleryItemWidth);

//Check width of Gallery div on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    var galleryWidth = $("#Gallery").innerWidth();
  });

$('.MoveLeft').click(function() {
  $(".GalleryItem2").animate({"left": "-=350px"}, "slow");
  $(".GalleryItem3").animate({"left": "-=280px"}, "slow");
  $(".GalleryItem").animate({
    left: '-=230',
  }, "slow", function() {
    position = $(".GalleryItem").position();
    galleryItemLeft = position.left;
    if(galleryItemLeft <= galleryWidth - galleryItemWidth) {
        $('.MoveLeft').removeAttr('disabled');}
        else{
        $('.MoveLeft').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.MoveRight').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });
});

$('.MoveRight').click(function() {
  $(".GalleryItem2").animate({"left": "+=350px"}, "slow");
  $(".GalleryItem3").animate({"left": "+=280px"}, "slow");
  $(".GalleryItem").animate({
    left: '+=230',
  }, "slow", function() {
    position = $(".GalleryItem").position();
    galleryItemLeft = position.left;
    if(galleryItemLeft >= "0") { 
        $('.MoveLeft').removeAttr('disabled');}
        else{
        $('.MoveLeft').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.MoveRight').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }   
  });
});

});


</script>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your result now?

Comment: it slides to the left and right but no buttons are deactivated when the condition it met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, to begin with remove this comma;

```
left: '-=230',
-------------^
```

and add px here

```
left: '-=230px'
------------^
```

then try to add this this;

```
if(galleryItemLeft <= 0) { 
    return false;
}
```

right after `$('.MoveLeft').click(function() {`
and the same for the right one

Comment: Thanks Johan. It has no effect on the slider. Do you mean put the condition above within the function or below(after) it ? Any other idea's ?

Comment: right before you start the sliding, that way the funtion will return and skip the rest of the block

Comment: When I add the condition there it causes the slider to stop working, it does not slide anymore. Any idea why?

Comment: that is what return false is doing, then something is wrong with your condition in you if statement

Comment: Am I using .removeAttr('disabled');} and .removeAttr('disabled');}
correctly ?

Comment: I dont see what element you are trying to remove the attribute from (will only work on inputs); but then again even if you disable a button for example the click event will still trigger, thats why i advice you to you a condition to stop the function even if the button is diabled. (you are using the right syntax for removeattr and attr) PS try to check if your if(galleryItemLeft >= "0"){ work correctly

Comment: the condition works but I'm not stopping the animation. I can either stop it when the sliding panel reaches a defined x position or when a certain number of clicks are counted. I'm not sure how to stop the animation, .stop() inst working for me, any ideas on how this can be achieved ?